# How to add/delete a Home page widget in the Allure report

Tags: python, widget, allure

Does anyone know how to add or delete a Home page widget(like ENVIRONMENT or EXECUTORS) in the Overview tab of the Allure report?

I chekced the Allure docs, only saw how to edit ENVIRONMENTS, and had no luck seeing anything relevant to this question

Comment: I saw someone posted an answer under the post that could be very helpful yesterday, but it got somehow deleted before I could vote for it. Is there any way I can still see the answer?

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?